# Pegar itens do array JSON

Tags: php, json

Galera, estou trabalhando com api do youtube e uma consulta me retorna o json abaixo. Como faço para pegar e imprimir cada item separadamente? Por exemplo quero imprimir cada "videoId". Como faço?

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/oqpVLfMmbzY_6j3oThpHVqTWBFU\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 19,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/dEwBoeecvF1DxUljodxRGtUsS_I\"",
   "id": "VTE0NzQ3NDkwMDExNDAxMjU5MzQzMzU1MDQ=",
   "contentDetails": {
    "upload": {
     "videoId": "H0fujYAi_qc"
    }
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/yZ6GjvR50A58SJxa_k7ATKpuoyY\"",
   "id": "QlVMMTQ3NDc0OTAwMTE0MDEyNTkzNDMzNzc0NA==",
   "contentDetails": {
    "bulletin": {
     "resourceId": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "H0fujYAi_qc"
     }
    }
   }
  },  
  {

   "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/S4iTb5HgOBL_i1Wz57Yf-FT8Jn0\"",
   "id": "VTE0NzQ3MjgzOTYxNDAxMjU5MzQzMzY5NzY=",
   "contentDetails": {
    "upload": {
     "videoId": "DrAsh8EfH7I"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ***chave*** que você procura, não fica sempre no mesmo lugar, então, com uma [função recursiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), varrer todo os elementos do `array` para busca da ***chaves*** com um determinado ***nome***. Também foi utilizado a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) para transformar o dado em texto `json` para `array`.

```
<?php

$json = '{
 "kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/oqpVLfMmbzY_6j3oThpHVqTWBFU\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 19,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

      "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/dEwBoeecvF1DxUljodxRGtUsS_I\"",
   "id": "VTE0NzQ3NDkwMDExNDAxMjU5MzQzMzU1MDQ=",
   "contentDetails": {
      "upload": {
          "videoId": "H0fujYAi_qc"
    }
   }
  },
  {
  "kind": "youtube#activity",
  "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/yZ6GjvR50A58SJxa_k7ATKpuoyY\"",
  "id": "QlVMMTQ3NDc0OTAwMTE0MDEyNTkzNDMzNzc0NA==",
  "contentDetails": {
      "bulletin": {
          "resourceId": 
          {
              "kind": "youtube#video",
             "videoId": "H0fujYAi_qc"
          }
      }
   }
  },  
  {
   "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/S4iTb5HgOBL_i1Wz57Yf-FT8Jn0\"",
   "id": "VTE0NzQ3MjgzOTYxNDAxMjU5MzQzMzY5NzY=",
   "contentDetails": {
      "upload": {
          "videoId": "DrAsh8EfH7I"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}';
```

---

```
<?php    
$array = json_decode($json, true);

function find_by_name_key($name, array $array, array &$values)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key === $name)
        {
            $values[$name][] = $value;
        }
        if (is_array($value)) find_by_name_key($name, $value, $values);
    }
}

$values = array();
find_by_name_key('videoId', $array['items'], $values);
var_dump($values);
```

[***Exemplo do código***](http://ideone.com/fork/BoslIb)

---

***Edição após comentário***

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array['items'] as $key => $values)
{
    if (isset($values['contentDetails']['upload']) && is_array($values['contentDetails']['upload'])){
        echo $values['contentDetails']['upload']['videoId'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

[***Exemplo da codigo - após o comentário***](http://ideone.com/fork/V5EmUu)

Comment: Opa cara...vlw amigo. Entendi o que me falou e funcionou. Voce pode me ajudar assim: agora que percebi que so quero os ids que possui o "contentDetails": {
      "upload": {.  Quero esses dis. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @Thiago foi feita a edição após o seu comentário.

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Ja me ajuda...so aparece esse erro "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: upload"...mas ja me ajuda! Vou marcar como certa, mas se tiver um fiz pra isso seria de muito ajuda.

Comment: @Thiago fiz edição para não ter a mensagem. No celular é complicado

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou!!!